# EntityFramework migration not removing 'IsRequired' from column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an `int` column which is currently mandatory

`builder.Property(p => p.PropertyArea).IsRequired();`

... but needs to be non-mandatory

`builder.Property(p => p.PropertyArea)`

But after applying `Add-Migration migrationName`, `update-database` etc there is no change to the column in sql server and it is still a `not null` column

Any idea why this might be the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change type of `PropertyArea` to `int?`. As the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#conventions) state:

> By convention, a property whose .NET type can contain null will be configured as optional, whereas properties whose .NET type cannot contain null will be configured as required. *For example, all properties with .NET value types (int, decimal, bool, etc.) are configured as required, and all properties with nullable .NET value types (int?, decimal?, bool?, etc.) are configured as optional.*